# Update using columns from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

I am trying to set an update using 2 tables but I don't know how to join the second one.

What i have now:

```
UPDATE Exp SET AMOUNT = 15, inner join Sal WHERE (DN = 120 AND NOM = 2122) 
OR (DN = 120 AND EAN = 2000000221412);

Table Exp:
  DN  |  NOM  |  AMOUNT  |
 .........................
  120 |  2122 |    0     |


Table Sal:
 NOM  |       EAN        |
..........................
 2122 |   2000000221412  |
```

Thanks.

Edit 1: Is there any way to do it without join?

Comment: why would you need to connect the table exp to table sal while there's no information from sal table that you need to update table exp into? you may just need to have where exists instead from sal table.

Answer (score 1):

**Generic Syntax** -

```
UPDATE A
SET foo = B.bar
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
  ON A.col1 = B.colx
WHERE ...
```

So you can try this -

```
UPDATE Exp SET AMOUNT = 15 
FROM Exp e 
INNER JOIN Sal s 
ON
  e.NOM = s.NOM
WHERE 
  e.DN=120 and s.EAN = 2000000221412; --some conditions. Edit according to your need
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax has the `join` as part of the `update`.  You also need a `join` key, which looks like `nom`:

```
UPDATE Exp inner join
       Sal
       ON exp.nom = sal.nom
    SET exp.AMOUNT = 15
    WHERE exp.DN = 120 AND (exp.NOM = 2122 OR sal.EAN = 2000000221412);
```